# VB Treeview causes vs32host.exe to stop working

Tags: windows, vb.net, treeview

this program is a Windows Form app written in VB 2008
I have a datatable (dtSubFolders) through which I am iterating to populate a treeview(tv_Folder_Hierarchy) by sending its NodesCollection to a recursive subroutine.  The NodesCollection seems to be populating correctly as evidenced by the data at the bottom.  However, when I expand the root, I see its 7 children then I get a  vs32host.exe has stopped working error.

```
   For Each row In dtSubFolders.Rows
        m_folder_Node = New TreeNode
        Get_TV_Node(tv_Folder_Hierarchy.Nodes, row(1).ToString)

        If Len(m_folder_Node.Name) > 0 Then
            m_folder_Node.Nodes.Add(row(0).ToString, row(2))
        Else
            tv_Folder_Hierarchy.Nodes.Add(row(0).ToString, row(2))
        End If
    Next

Private Sub Get_TV_Node(ByRef Nodes As TreeNodeCollection, ByVal Name As String)

    Dim node As TreeNode

    If Len(m_folder_Node.Name) = 0 Then
        For Each node In Nodes
            If node.Name = Name Then
                m_folder_Node = node
                Exit For
            Else
                If node.Nodes.Count > 0 Then Get_TV_Node(node.Nodes, Name)
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

> ID      Parent  Kids    Text 
> 1811    None    7   Root Folder 
> 1818    1811    40  Award Creation 
> 1828    1818    0   Award Creation Sub 1 
> 1819    1818    0   Award Creation Sub 2 
> 1824    1818    0   Award Creation Sub 3 
> 1839    1818    0   Award Creation Sub 4

Answer (score 0):

PLICK - Problem Lay In (between the) Chair and the Keyboard.  In my rush I hadn't noticed bad untrapped code in the NodeMouseClick event.

BAH!